# Connecting local SSMS to Sql Server High Availability running on virtual machines in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

We are currently running a High Availabilty SQL Server using two VMs in Azure with a Load Balancer. We would like to be able to connect SSMS running locally on our machines to that SQL Server and are running into some issues that I hope are easily solved by someone who knows what they are doing.

[image: SQL-HighAvailability-Azure]

How do I configure the NSG and other azure bits to allow me to connect my local SSMS to this SQL server farm?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure the NSG and other azure bits to allow me to connect
>   my local SSMS to this SQL server farm?

Do you create Public IP addresses with those VMs, if yes, we can add port 1433 to NSG inbound rules, and connect it via public IP addresses.

Also we should add port 1433 to windows firewall inbound rules.

Comment: There is a PIP on the load balancer, but not the VMs themselves. Will I have to add PIP's to those?

Comment: Yes, we can add pip to them.